# How can I have Skype for Business automatically join meetings planned in the Outlook Calendar?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, skype, skype-for-business

I'm on a Windows 7 Enterprise computer. My company uses Microsoft products like Skype for Business, Office 365, etc.

I have meetings on the calendar throughout the day listed in my Outlook calendar and they always have Skype link in them to join the virtual meeting. I lose time by having to stop, open the meeting invite, and click the link ahead of time. Also, sometimes I'm busy and forget to join, after dismissing the meeting reminder.

Is there a way to have it just automatically log me into the Skype meeting when it's time for the meeting? This would allow me to keep working until I actually hear people in the meeting talking, and it would keep me from forgetting to sign into a meeting on time.

Comment: I'm not going to be near a computer for a while to write and test the VBA you need, but if someone else fancies the challenge then you need to create an `Application_Reminder` event which then scans the email for the Skype URL in the message body and launches it.

Comment: Don't you get Outlook reminder windows for the SfB meeting and can click "Join Online"? Or is the meeting not [properly defined](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-a-Skype-for-Business-meeting-in-Outlook-b8305620-d16e-4667-989d-4a977aad6556) by its creator?

Comment: Try creating an applet in the iftt platform https://platform.ifttt.com/

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong, latest SFB will pop a balloon on bottom-right corner when its due - single click will put you in conference on time.

This has lot of feature to check, like you accepted it or declined, dismissed the reminder or not, are you still active or away from the desk, you want to be muted or should it open in full screen if any presentation going on.

You can put this in uservoice or MS board for enhancement, :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to auto answer but you can open the calendar icon in Skype and join any scheduled call from there. Easier and quicker than opening the invite.