# Any Way To Auto-join Skype Meetings When They Start (MacOS And Windows)?

Tags: skype-for-business

Is there a way to auto-join Skype-for-Business meetings when they start? I'm hoping to find a solution for both MacOS and Windows. Outlook is an option.

[This similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1207161/how-can-i-have-skype-for-business-automatically-join-meetings-planned-in-the-out) has one answer, though it requires a click (not automated) and seems limited to Windows builds of SFB.